# how to improve the performance of bulk transaction in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, transactions

i am working with java spring mvc with JPA and hibernate. If i want to process 2000 transactions, can i process them in batches of 500 transactions using threads putting in consideration that the single transaction should be processed by the same thread?is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 2000 transactions?

Comment: 2000 request to do transactional operation. Single operation is money transfer (debit from account and credit from other acount) in my data base.

Comment: When i say transaction i mean transactional methods that work with transaction object type.

Comment: please, tell me weather it is clear or should i edit my question ?

Comment: Is it a batch system ? Online system ?

Comment: online system...

Comment: Do you have some code? Did you try something already ?

Comment: not yet, i want to see my options first

Comment: So to be clear you want to avoid one insert at time ? And executing 2000 insert one by one?

Comment: yes, and to divide it to 500 batches in parallel.

Comment: i really appreciate your care. thnx in advance.

Comment: Np ;-). Last question..Which database ? Postgres?

Comment: My SQL.........

Comment: did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't enable batching by default. This means that it'll send a separate SQL statement for each insert.

To insert so massive dataset in once you should use batch insert.
Here the hibernate properties :
`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50` and `hibernate.order_inserts = true`

The first property tells Hibernate to collect inserts in batches of 50 (50 is only used here for as example..). The order_inserts property tells Hibernate to take the time to group inserts by entity, creating larger batches.

Then you should choose between explicit or implicit flushing.

1. Implicit: just set the batch size property and hibernate will do the rest.
2. Explicit `flush` and `clear`

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
        A a = new A();
        entityManager.persist(a);   
}
```

So why using 2nd option?

When we persist an entity, Hibernate stores it in the persistence context. For example, if we persist 2,000 entities in one transaction, we'll end up having 2,000 entity instances in memory, possibly causing an OutOfMemory
...

Other problem... as you said you're using MySQL.
hibernate batch option not work with IdGenerator `IDENTITY` so you can't use batch insert with `AUTO-INCREMENT` feature of mysql. As sequence generation doesn't exist in MySQL you're stuck with `TABLE` generator. But table generator is less performant than identity one.
To mention Vlad mihalcea (quote from his famous book `High Performance Java Persistence`)

> When using MySQL and need lot of inserts It is a good idea to use JOOQ framework for that.